# How to test String.prototype.includes in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I have an `ember-cli 0.2.7` using `Ember.js 1.12.0` app with a piece of code that looks like:

`controllers/cart.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    footwearInCart: Ember.computed('model.@each.category', function() {
        return this.get('model').any(product => product.get('category').includes('Footwear'));
    })
});
```

It goes through all the objects in the model and returns true if their category property has 'footwear' in it.

I'm trying to test it like so:

`tests/unit/controllers/cart-test.js`

```
import { moduleFor, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';

var products = [Ember.Object.create({name: 'shoe', category: 'Footwear', subTotal: 10}), Ember.Object.create({name: 'shirt', subTotal: 20})];

var model = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: Ember.A(products)
});

moduleFor('controller:cart', {
  beforeEach() {
    this.controller = this.subject();
  }
});

test('footwearInCart property works', function(assert) {
  this.controller.set('model', model);

  assert.equal(this.controller.get('footwearInCart'), true, 'The footwearInCart function returns true if the category property of product in cart contains the word "Footwear"');
});
```

The code works the way it should when I run the app, but `PhantomJS` apparently does not recognise the .includes method. (The method is documented here [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

How can I get PhantomJS to recognize the .includes method?

Thanks!

Comment: `includes` is implemented now only in Chrome. Your code cannot work in Firefox, Safari and IE as well in PhantomJS

Comment: Managed to make it work using a polyfill.  Tested it in FF, Safari, & PhantomJS and it worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently PhantomJS doesn't implement ES6 features properly. Luckily `String.prototype.includes` is quite easy to polyfill. You can choose if you want to do that in the test suite or the controller. The polyfill code is:

```
if (!String.prototype.includes) {
  String.prototype.includes = function() {'use strict';
    return String.prototype.indexOf.apply(this, arguments) !== -1;
  };
}
```

Either put it right before the `assert` call (you might want to use a flag to remember of you added the polyfill and remove it after the `assert`), or do it in the module itself, before or after the `export` block.

Comment: @Amit is there a general phantomjs es6 polyfill that works? I have tried babel-core, es6-shim and they all don't solve the `includes` problem...

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy - I don't know that there is one, but that doesn't mean there isn't. I was simply able to find a simple solution to the particular problem in this case.

Answer (score 6):

While the selected answer is correct, I think it's worth noting that adding this into the specific test is not good enough for most apps; I'd suggest creating a `vendor/phantom-js-polyfills.js` that contains this polyfill (plus any others that come up down the line) and then inside your `ember-cli-build.js` you can conditionally load it in:

```
  if (EmberApp.env() === 'test') {
    app.import('vendor/phantom-js-polyfills.js');
  }
```

Comment: I ended up using a polyfill in the app in a similar manner because I also wanted to support browsers that didn't use this method (like safari)

Comment: I think in addition, you can use plugins like this to be included into your test suite, in your compiled files or perhaps simply include it in the index.html: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.includes

Comment: Yeah, this is probably overkill. I put the polyfills for phantomJS in `tests/test-helper.js`. I'll have to check it when I upgrade Ember occasionally, but I always like fewer moving parts.

Answer (score -1):

I've used the following polyfill recently which got the job done.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-polyfill-string-includes