# Test PhantomJS Array.prototype.includes() in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, phantomjs

In my angular app, unit tests of components that use Array.prototype.includes() will pass when run with Chrome, but fail when run with PhantomJS.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31360504/10812434) give some suggestions for the same problem in Ember, but is there a more recent solution that works with Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! As of now (January 2019), you can simply use a `core-js` module. To your app's `polyfills.ts` file, add:

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

PhantomJS then should handle `.includes()` correctly.

Comment: Also: PhantomJS is too old now and is discontinued. It's better to migrate to `puppeteer`.